# Set-up include path for menu navigation so page links know where the site root is located in order to not break links

Tags: php, hyperlink, navigation, include, directory

I have not been successful getting my remote server environment to behave like my testing server environment -nor visa versa- in regard to my navigations "include code" that I've included on my various pages (these pages reside inside other folders in the site).

My Menu shows up fine in the pages calling the include to this page this way...

```
<?php include("../includes/navigation.php"); ?>
```

But my MAMP testing server seems to want me to also add the root folder in addition to my provided link in each of the menu items, so I altered the link by adding my site root folder, like this...

```
<a href="/mysite/courses/list.php"
```

and navigation menu seemed to work, going inside one folder and back out into another (then I realized it was no good when I tested it on my remote server).

I got bad/broken links.

So I changed to something like this for the remote server...

```
 <a href="/courses/list.php"
```

Links seem to work on the remote, but I needed to fix it so that the code I go with works on both the testing and remote servers...

So, I'm trying to ~~understand/control/and fix~~ my include_once code to provide proper menu navigation for all my various pages whether I am on my testing server or on my remote server and wether I am in one folder or another. Is this possible? And am I approaching this the right way?

(Currently, I have my root folder with an index page, then inside that, I have 3 folders with misc pages inside them, one of these folders (includes) holds my navigation.php page)

I have been searching for how to get my pages (located in various folders) to recognize where they were, in relation to the sites root folder. As a result of  searching I concluded to insert this code into the list.php page in my "courses folder"...

```
   <?php
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/includes/navigation.php";
   include_once($path);
   ?>
```

on one of my pages and then tested it in my testing server (MAMP) - but now the menu does not even show up...I also tried...

```
       <?php
   $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "../includes/navigation.php";
   include_once($path);
   ?>
```

So I am seeking help in understanding - what am I missing in my understanding/execution to get the pages now to show the navigation menu as well as know where it is in relation to the root.

I would welcome any comments to help me understand how to connect the dots to solve this problem. As I read in another post saying to someone else there was a problem with where their site root folder was pointing (that it was pointing to the server root folder, not the site root folder)-

How would I know if this is what my problem is? How do you check this?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem going on. What I did to solve it was instead of simply using "..includes/nav.php" I used an absolute path to the file. It should look something like this:

"var/www/html/includes/nav.php"

This specifies the exact route to the file. You can find this through your hosting file management page. Log into the file management, find the nav file within the folders, and use the exact url of the file.